# How can I create a string from just the first line of my UITextView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsstring, uitextview

I am making a UITextView which is similar to notes.app, where the first line of the textView is used as the title. I need to create a new string which contains only the first line of text. So far I've come up with this:

```
NSRange startRange = NSMakeRange(0, 1);
NSRange titleRange = [noteTextView.text lineRangeForRange:startRange];  
NSString *titleString = [noteTextView.text substringToIndex:titleRange.length];
NSLog(@"The title is: %@", titleString);
```

The only problem with this is that it relies on the user pressing Return. I've also tried using a loop to find the number of characters in the first line:

```
CGSize lineSize = [noteTextView.text sizeWithFont:noteTextView.font 
                                constrainedToSize:noteTextView.frame.size 
                                    lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
int textLength =1;

while ((lineSize.width < noteTextView.frame.size.width) && 
       ([[noteTextView.text substringToIndex:textLength] length] < [noteTextView.text length])) 
{
    lineSize = [[noteTextView.text substringToIndex:textLength] sizeWithFont:noteTextView.font 
                                                           constrainedToSize:noteTextView.frame.size 
                                                               lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    textLength = textLength+1;
}


NSLog(@"Length is %i", textLength);
```

But I've got this wrong somewhere - it returns the total number of characters, instead of the number on the first line.

Does anyone know an easier/better way of doing this?

Comment: What do you exactly want?i mean you want only first line of textview?or you want first line completed with "."?

Comment: @dks1725 I just want the first visible line of the UITextView.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a much better way with CoreText, but I'll throw this out there just because it came to mind off the top of my head.

You could add characters one by one to an NSMutableString *title while

```
[title sizeWithFont:noteTextView.font].width < noteTextView.frame.size.width
```

then drop the last one, obviously doing the necessary bounds checking along the way and dropping the last added character if necessary.

But sizeWithFont is sloooooow. So if you're doing this often you might want to consider another definition of 'title' - say, at first word break after 20 chars.

But again, CoreText might yield more possibilities.

Comment: Also, of course, stop looking once you encounter a line delimiter (LF, CR)

Comment: Good suggestion, but I've been running into all sorts of problems trying to implement it, like range exceptions when cutting/pasting.

Comment: Hmmm. Playing with notes.app some more, it seems all they've done is what I did at the beginning - the title is everything up to the first carriage return, which then gets arbitrarily truncated to fit in the UITable where you see the note titles. Maybe that's all I need to do then.

Comment: Use this solution, except as a binary search for the upper bound instead of adding one character at a time. I've done this sort of thing several times and the speed seems acceptable, (for up to whole paragraphs at least.)

Comment: @Daniel can you explain in a bit more detail what you mean?

Comment: @Ric Levy I mean don't add characters one by one. You know the length of the string, so start with x = length, y = x / 2 and then check your predicate against y, if true then y = x / 2, x = x / 2 and try again, if false y += x / 2, x = x / 2 and try again. Once x == 1 you will know that y points to the position in the string you are looking for (or one past, I'm not sure off hand.) Doing it this way will reduce the number of times you have to run through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand the code you're having above. Wouldn't it be simpler do just find the first *line* of text in the string, e.g. until a CR or LF terminates the first line?
And if there is no CR or LF, then you take the entire text as you have only one line then.

Of course, this will give you not what is visible in the first line in case the line is longer and gets wrapped, but I think that using lineRangeForRange doesn't do this, either, or does it?

And if your only concern is that "the user has to press enter" to make it work, then why not simply append a newline char to the text before testing for the first line's length?

Comment: I want the user to be able to type as normal, and at the point the line first wraps (or they press return - whichever comes first) - that is my new string. I.e. when you look at the full UITextView, whatever happens to be on the first line is the title. `lineRangeForRange` doesn't work for the reason you mention (it has no way of knowing where the UITextField wraps) - hence my question. :)

Comment: Ah, I see now. Unless Ball's suggestion is enough, maybe CoreText is your candidate. Keep in mind that CoreText is also used on OSX, so maybe you should not limit your question to iOS, getting broader attention here? Sorry to be of no real help.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, nonetheless! I've changed the tag to plain cocoa instead of cocoa-touch.

Answer (score -1):

See how many characters can fit in one line of your text view and use that number in a substringToIndex: method. Like this:
Type out the same character repeatedly and count how many fit in one line. Make sure to use a wide letter to ensure reliability. Use a capital g or m or q or w or whatever is widest in the font you're using.

Say 20 characters can fit in one line.

Then do

```
NSString *textViewString = notesTextView.text;
NSString *titleString = [textViewString substringToIndex:20]
```

Just use the `titleString` as the title.